# Chomp all keys of a map (using less code)

Tags: perl

I'm trying to do something like

```
my %my_map = map { chomp($_) => 1 } @my_arr;
```

That doesn't do what I expect it to do, so I need to:

```
my @chomped_arr = @my_arr;
chomp @chomped_arr;
my %my_map = map { $_ => 1 } @chomped_arr;
```

What is the shorter way to do it?

Comment: Calling `chomp()` multiple times doesn't make sense from performance perspective, so `chomp @chomped_arr;` or `chomp(my @chomped_arr = @my_arr);` is better in that regard. Also it is good to avoid `map` when slice can do the job => `my %my_map; @my_map{@chomped_arr} = (1) x @chomped_arr;`

Comment: *"it is good to avoid map when slice can do the job"* Why do you say that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem with your `map` is that `chomp` inside [modifies its argument, and returns some unrelated and usually useless value](http://blogs.perl.org/users/joel_berger/2012/02/should-perl-have-an-rchomp-function.html). The solution is to create temporary variable that holds copy of `$_`, `chomp` it, and then use it as key:

```
my %my_map = map { my $k = $_; chomp $k; $k => 1 } @my_arr;
```

Comment: You could also do `map { s/\n$//r => 1 }`

Comment: @HåkonHægland That doesn't take `$/` into account. In most cases it should work, though.

Answer (score 5):

The gotcha here is `chomp` modifies the variable, but doesn't return it. So it won't work in a map.

A workaround that I like is to use the `r` regex modifier -

```
my %my_map = map { s|\n||gr => 1 } @my_arr;
```

Which returns the modified result, but does so *without* altering the original (which would change `@arr`).

Note - the above doesn't quite chomp - it removes any linefeeds. (You can of course, stick a `$` in your regex. e.g. `s|\n$||r` )

`r` regex flag is a newer feature (not *that* new). Can't recall OTOH which version of perl it was introduced in.

Can do it this with file handle input too :

```
my %stuff = map { s|\n||gr => 1 } <$fh>;
```

Strictly though, `chomp` removes `$/` from the end of line so you might want

```
s|\Q$/\E\z||r
```

Which I think strictly reproduces `chomp` - but this might be a tradeoff of readability.

Comment: For clarity, I would modify the code snippets to use the `\n$` variant you mention, since the others aren't remotely equivalent to `chomp`.

Comment: True, but that might be more like `$/$`  may edit when I am near a proper keyboard again :)

Comment: I particularly enjoy the last edit. Reduced redability somehow has a perverse glory about it in Perl.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that the contents of your file shouldn't have been read into an array in the first place

This is a better way

```
my %my_map;
while ( <> ) {
    chomp;
    $my_map{$_} = 1;
}
```

or, if you *must* have the file contents in an array, then

```
my %my_map = do {
    chomp(my @temp = @my_arr);
    map { $_ => 1 } @temp;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with this is that `chomp` doesn't return an altered value, it mutates its argument in place. One way I often like to solve this is to create a new function `chomped` which does work as a pure function.

```
sub chomped { my $v = shift; chomp $v; return $v }
```

You can then use that in the map

```
my %my_map = map { chomped($_) => 1 } @my_arr;
```